# Is mesh networking possible through Safari on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mesh-network

Since iOS 7 was released, it's possible to connect devices through a mesh network using the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](http://bgr.com/2014/03/24/ios-7-mesh-network-feature/) that can be used for app development.

My question is, could the same type of connectivity that's achievable through an app apply to Safari? In other words, does Safari's Internet connection mechanism force it to go through iOS' cellular data / wifi, or is it possible to allow the user to browse through a mesh?

I don't know much about iOS development and I suspect that websites opened through Safari don't have the authority to determine the sort of Internet connection mechanism that the device uses, but I wanted to ask if this is achievable by asking the user for permission or something like that.

Something that comes to mind is users' ability to download photos from websites to their file-systems, but then again they are the ones who are making the requests --the websites aren't asking for permission to save the photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.  You have no way to control Safari's network connection mechanism other than the options found in Settings->Safari.